# Copy values from column X+2 (two to the right of X) into column X

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and one every three columns has a name (the others are unnamed 1,2,3...).

I want values in the columns that have names to be equal to the value of two columns to the right of that.

I was using `df.columns.get_loc("X")` and I can use this to correctly select my desired column using `df.iloc[:,X]`,

but I can't do Y = X +2 on pandas to do `df.iloc[:,X] = df.iloc[:,Y]` because X is not just an integer.

Any ideas on how to solve this? It can be a different way to get column X to have the same values as two columns to the right of X.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this would work, change 8 to fit your columns, or len(columns)//3*3

```
for n in range(0,8,3):
    df.iloc[:,n]= df.iloc[:,n+2]
```

it doesn't seem we can assign a multi column to a multi column, not sure if that is possible

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that get_loc gives me False, False, True instead of n. So I can't do the n+2 part.